# $scope in AngularJS modal doesn't pass data into the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I have created the following controller that display a list of results and that opens a modal when a specific button is clicked:

```
angular.
module('panelList')
  .component('panelList', {
  templateUrl: '/panel-list/panel-list.template.html',
  controller: ['Panel', 'PanelSelection', '$scope', '$location', '$uibModal',
    function PanelListController(Panel, PanelSelection, $scope, $location, $uibModal) {

      $scope.maxAbv = 2;
      $scope.minAbv = 12;
      $scope.maxIbu = 0;
      $scope.minIbu = 100;

      this.allPanelsRetrieved = (index, before, filterParams) => {
        let allPanels = before;
        const params = Object.assign({},
          { page: index, per_page: 80 },
          filterParams);
        Panel.query(params).$promise.then(data => {
          if (data.length > 0) {
            allPanels.push(...data);
            return this.allPanelsRetrieved(index+1, allPanels, filterParams);
          } else {
            return allPanels;
          }
        });
        return allPanels;
      };

      $scope.getPanels = () => {
       const filterParams = {};
       filterParams.abv_lt = $scope.minAbv;
       filterParams.abv_gt = $scope.maxAbv;
       filterParams.ibu_lt = $scope.minIbu;
       filterParams.ibu_gt = $scope.maxIbu;
       $scope.currentPagePanels = this.allPanelsRetrieved(1,[], filterParams);
      };

      $scope.showDetails = (panelSelected) => {
        PanelSelection.setPanelSelected(panelSelected);
        $uibModal.open({
          component: "panelDetail",
          scope: $scope,
          bindToController: true,
        })
      };
  }]
});
```

The controller for the modal is specified here:

```
angular.
module('panelDetail').
component('panelDetail', {
  templateUrl: '/panel-detail/panel-detail.template.html',
  controller: ['PanelSelection', '$scope','$uibModal',
    function PanelDetailController(PanelSelection, $scope, $uibModal, $uibModalInstance) {

      $scope.ok = () => {
        $uibModalInstance.close();
      };

      let panelSelected = PanelSelection.getPanelSelected();
      $scope.panel = panelSelected;
      console.log(panelSelected);
      $scope.foodPairings = panelSelected.food_pairing.join(", ");
      $scope.allIngredients = this.getFormattedIngredients(panelSelected.ingredients);
      $scope.method = this.getFormattedMethod(panelSelected.method);

      this.getFormattedIngredients = (ingredients) => {
        const listOfIngredients = [];
        Object.keys(ingredients).forEach(key => {
          if(Array.isArray(ingredients[key])){
            for(let ingredient of ingredients[key]){
              listOfIngredients.push(
                `- ${ingredient.name} ${key} (${ingredient.amount.value} ${ingredient.amount.unit})`
                  .concat(ingredient.add != undefined ? ', added in the '+ingredient.add:'',
                    ingredient.attribute != undefined ? ', attribute: '+ingredient.attribute:'','.')
              );
            }
          }else{
            listOfIngredients.push(`- ${ingredients[key]} ${key}.`);
          }
        });
        return listOfIngredients;
      };

      $scope.getFormattedMethod = (method) => {
        const listOfMethodProcedures = [];
        Object.keys(method).forEach(key => {
          if(Array.isArray(method[key])){
            for(let methodProcedure of method[key]){
              listOfMethodProcedures.push(
                `- ${key} at ${methodProcedure.temp.value} ${methodProcedure.temp.unit} `
                  .concat(methodProcedure.duration != undefined ? 'for '+methodProcedure.duration +' min.' : '.')
              );
            }
          }else{
            listOfMethodProcedures.push(`- ${key}.`);
          }
        });
        return listOfMethodProcedures;
      };
  }
  ]
});
```

The modal is open correctly but the values inside are not taken from the scope, as they should, but they are displayed as {{value}}. In few words, the $scope passed doesn't act as scope. Moreover I get the following error:

> TypeError: this.getFormattedIngredients is not a function
>       at new PanelDetailController

Where the error may be? How to pass successfully a scope from one controller to another for modal?

Comment: I think it's not a scope issue but the TypeError make the linking crash. You use `this.getFormattedIngredients` before its definition. You must define `this.getFormattedIngredients` before `$scope.allIngredients`.

Comment: still get the same issue

Comment: Are you sure your template is correct? Do you use `{{$ctrl.value}}` syntax?

Comment: yes, I use in the template,as an example: <h3 class="modal-title">{{panel.name}}</h3>

Comment: using {{$ctrl.panel.name}} doesn't solve the issue

Comment: does the function get called @Anto

Comment: much helpful if you could create a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `scope: $scope` pass values using

```
resolve: { scope: $scope }
```

Comment: thanks, it now works. One small issue has persisted: the
$uibModalInstance.close();
doesn't work, as the modal doesn't close when the OK button is closed. What change should I make to fix this?

Comment: @Anto see if $uibModalInstance is getting properly injected into the code. If not you can try $uibModalInstance.dismiss() if that serves your purpose

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `getFormattedIngredients` function before it gets declared. So this is not a `$scope` issue. You need to declare the function before it gets called. One way to solve such an issue is going with the angular Styleguide provided by `John Papa`. [Angular Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)

Assign your function at the top of your Component/Controller/Service and use function expressions instead of function declarations.

```
function PanelDetailController(PanelSelection, $scope, $uibModal,$uibModalInstance) {

  this.getFormattedIngredients = getFormattedIngredients;

  // You can call your function from here without getting an error 
  // Other Code..
  function getFormattedIngredients() {}
```